# not maven project export war

Tags: java, maven

(Translated to Google Translator.)

I would like to extract a WAR from a maven project using SVN + maven.

sample pom.xml and generate maven package on linux distribution server
There are libraries in web-inf / lib.

I want to extract war without adding dependencies to pom.xml one by one.

Thank you.

---

pom.xml

```
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
                  <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <archive>
                <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

---

### maven clean package error

```
[WARNING] COMPILATION WARNING : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] /home/maven_test/xxxx/xxxx/src/com/xxxx/util/DesEncrypt.java:[5,16] sun.misc.BASE64Decoder is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] /home/maven_test/xxxx/xxxx/src/com/xxxx/util/DesEncrypt.java:[6,16] sun.misc.BASE64Encoder is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] /home/maven_test/xxxx/xxxx/src/com/xxxx/util/DesEncrypt.java:[71,25] sun.misc.BASE64Encoder is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] /home/maven_test/xxxx/xxxx/src/com/xxxx/util/DesEncrypt.java:[71,53] sun.misc.BASE64Encoder is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] /home/maven_test/xxxx/xxxx/src/com/xxxx/util/DesEncrypt.java:[95,25] sun.misc.BASE64Decoder is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
[WARNING] /home/maven_test/xxxx/xxxx/src/com/xxxx/util/DesEncrypt.java:[95,53] sun.misc.BASE64Decoder is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
[INFO] 7 warnings 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/maven_test/xxxx/xxxx/src/com/xxxx/service/ConfirmService.java:[6,26] package javax.servlet.http does not exist
[ERROR] /home/maven_test/xxxx/xxxx/src/com/xxxx/service/ConfirmService.java:[7,26] package javax.servlet.http does not exist
[ERROR] /home/maven_test/xxxx/xxxx/src/com/xxxx/service/ConfirmService.java:[9,30] package org.springframework.ui does not exist
[ERROR] /home/maven_test/xxxx/xxxx/src/com/xxxx/util/EgovMap.java:[3,42] package org.apache.commons.collections.map does not exist
[ERROR] /home/maven_test/xxxx/xxxx/src/com/xxxx/util/EgovMap.java:[5,30] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class ListOrderedMap
[ERROR] /home/maven_test/xxxx/xxxx/src/com/xxxx/service/ConfirmService.java:[28,25] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class HttpServletRequest
  location: interface com.xxxx.service.ConfirmService
```

---

```
----- WEB-INF/lib files----------
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  246036 2019-04-23 14:37 org.springframework.transaction-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  829601 2019-04-23 14:37 org.springframework.context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  442400 2019-04-23 14:37 org.springframework.core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   20682 2019-04-23 14:37 jstl.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   71442 2019-04-23 14:37 commons-discovery-0.2.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  148817 2019-04-23 14:37 commons-dbcp-1.3.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  176283 2019-04-23 14:37 org.springframework.expression-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   14435 2019-04-23 14:37 json_simple.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  100472 2019-04-23 14:37 commons-pool-1.5.6.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  330305 2019-04-23 14:37 core.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   23737 2019-04-23 14:37 json-simple-1.1.1.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1115161 2019-04-23 14:37 javaee.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   59590 2019-04-23 14:37 commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  743361 2019-04-23 14:37 jxl.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   31408 2019-04-23 14:37 org.springframework.web.struts-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2427010 2019-04-23 14:37 commons-compress-1.18-javadoc.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  481534 2019-04-23 14:37 log4j-1.2.16.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  103165 2019-04-23 14:37 Java-WebSocket-1.3.0.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  466359 2019-04-23 14:37 sqljdbc4.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  378235 2019-04-23 14:37 org.springframework.orm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  159509 2019-04-23 14:37 commons-io-2.0.1.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  541624 2019-04-23 14:37 commons-compress-1.18-sources.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  106819 2019-04-23 14:37 org.springframework.context.support-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   30658 2019-04-23 14:37 jstl-api-1.2.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    7551 2019-04-23 14:37 org.springframework.instrument-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  355030 2019-04-23 14:37 mail.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  559366 2019-04-23 14:37 commons-collections-3.1.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  194208 2019-04-23 14:37 xml-apis.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   60686 2019-04-23 14:37 commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  274404 2019-04-23 14:37 barcode4j.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  331474 2019-04-23 14:37 org.springframework.aop-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  190432 2019-04-23 14:37 gson-2.2.4.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   31605 2019-04-23 14:37 commons-logging.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  312552 2019-04-23 14:37 javax.websocket-api-1.1-javadoc.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  199060 2019-04-23 14:37 org.springframework.jms-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  589253 2019-04-23 14:37 org.springframework.beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  315805 2019-04-23 14:37 commons-lang3-3.1.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  181243 2019-04-23 14:37 sitemesh-2.4.1.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   50621 2019-04-23 14:37 org.springframework.aspects-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  298829 2019-04-23 14:37 commons-configuration-1.6.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  401762 2019-04-23 14:37 org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  305001 2019-04-23 14:37 commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1536797 2019-04-23 14:37 ojdbc14.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  591748 2019-04-23 14:37 commons-compress-1.18.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  667464 2019-04-23 14:37 jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.5.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  393259 2019-04-23 14:37 standard.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  229729 2019-04-23 14:37 org.springframework.test-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  227411 2019-04-23 14:37 jackson-core-asl-1.8.5.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   23563 2019-04-23 14:37 saxpath.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   20310 2019-04-23 14:37 javase.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  116039 2019-04-23 14:37 aspectjrt-1.6.8.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   11468 2019-04-23 14:37 org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  572266 2019-04-23 14:37 org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   70242 2019-04-23 14:37 org.springframework.oxm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  190874 2019-04-23 14:37 org.springframework.web.portlet-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   46725 2019-04-23 14:37 commons-codec-1.3.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   23874 2019-04-23 14:37 bitlyj-2.0.0.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1690239 2019-04-23 14:37 aspectjweaver-1.6.11.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  384363 2019-04-23 14:37 ibatis-2.3.4.726.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  284220 2019-04-23 14:37 commons-lang-2.6.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  540819 2019-04-23 14:37 org.springframework.web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  180792 2019-04-23 14:37 commons-net-1.4.1.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   53079 2019-04-23 14:37 org.springframework.asm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   36710 2019-04-23 14:37 javax.websocket-api-1.1.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  322386 2019-04-23 14:37 backport-util-concurrent.jar
------------------------------------
```

Comment: First follow convention over configuration `src/main/java` production code `src/test/java` test code and `src/main/webapp` for WAR ...

Comment: I'm sorry I did not understand your words.
(Google Translator) :(

Comment: Follow the convention see https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html